# how to use opus DTX from opensource OPUS demo binary

Tags: opus

i want help in OPUS DTX

1.how OPUS DTX is working.
2.how opus encoder and decoder works for dtx
3.Is there any bit representation for DTX in OPUS

From rfc When DTX is enabled, only one frame is encoded
 every 400 milliseconds it didnt works for me with opus_demo binary.
 please help with OPUS DTX.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Opus over a network, using a protocol such as RTP where the packets are timestamped, DTX may be enabled if you want to reduce the packets sent during periods where there is no voice activity.  A packet would still be sent about every 400 ms, updating background noise.  Using the packet timestamps the receiver can determine the duration of any gaps and fill them in with the background noise to keep it sounding natural.

Enable DTX in the encoder using `opus_encoder_ctl(enc, OPUS_SET_DTX(1));`, or with the `-dtx` option on `opus_demo`.  Then, simply do not send any packets produced by the encoder with a length of 2 bytes or less.  (These "DTX packets" are just zero-length frames, with a normal 1- or 2-byte packet header (TOC), and do not contain any audio data.)  Packets with a length larger than 2 bytes should be sent as usual.

The receiver should use normal packet loss concealment to handle missing packets, in the same manner as it would handle packet loss.  In particular it can call `opus_decode()` with `data = NULL`, `len = 0`, and `frame_size` equal to the size of the missing frame(s), and the decoder will generate audio data to conceal the missing frame(s).

Comment: Should it work as `--set-ctl-int 4016=1` option for `opusenc`?